# Mingw32's ld.exe cannot find -lz

Tags: zlib, mingw32

I have a project in which I need to create an executable file. In the makefile which has the rules for this executable I have this:

```
LIBS=-lws2_32 -llibrary -llua53 -ldwarf -lz -lelf
```

When I try to create the executable by running the make command I get the following error:

> ```
> > c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
> > cannot find -lz
> ```

Now as I understand -lz is for specifing to include the zlib library. I have that installed on my system. Still I get the error.  Do I need to include some path in my env variables? I have searched a lot but found no answer. Please help me correct this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could add `-L<path>` before the `-lz` command where  points to the location of `libz.a` and/or `libz.dll.a`.